# Python application tested in Travis spawns web browser, which blocks, and Travis times out

Tags: python, travis-ci

I have been testing a Python application under Travis, and this has worked really well. However, I am now trying to test the following statement:

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(outputFile)
```

When this line executes, Travis logs:

> ≪ ↑ ↓ Viewing <index.html>
>
> No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
>
> The build has been terminated

How do I stop Travis from being blocked by this code spawning an external application (a browser - presumably Firefox)? I run the tests as follows:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" nosetests -s --nologcapture -A 'not slow' -v --with-id --with-xcoverage --with-xunit --verbose --cover-package=qgis2web
```

I've also tried the following alternate ways of calling `xvfb` (from https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/):

```
- before_script:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3 # give xvfb some time to start
```

or:

```
-before_install:
  - "/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16"
```

and then calling the tests directly:

```
nosetests -s --nologcapture -A 'not slow' -v --with-id --with-xcoverage --with-xunit --verbose --cover-package=qgis2web
```

Both result in "Cannot connect to X" type errors.

How can I stop `webbrowser` from blocking?

Edit:
The tests are written in Python, too.

Comment: `command &` will work for 86% of cases

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь Sorry, can you expand? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: To run `command` in a non-blocking fashion you can do `command &`

Comment: The `webbrowser` command I refer to is part of a test suite written in Python. `command &` gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs for webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) it says

> Under Unix, graphical browsers are preferred under X11, but text-mode browsers will be used if graphical browsers are not available or an X11 display isn’t available. If text-mode browsers are used, the calling process will block until the user exits the browser.

This indicates that you will need to install a graphical browser on the target platform (travis) to get this command working.

However, you might also consider that there is not much feedback you will get for useful test results, if just *some* browser is spawned in the background over which you have no control. So you may instead want to mock the webbrowser module for tests and check if the appropriate function is called or just skip this call on the test environment.

Comment: I read that in the `webbrowser` docs, but I thought that Travis came with Firefox installed. I don't know if I have the issue of running the tests via xvfb-run meaning that `webbrowser` cannot find an X session ("Note: Don’t run xvfb directly, as it does not handle multiple concurrent instances that way" - https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-a-GUI). That could mean that it defaults to a blocking text browser. But I could not get the other Travis recommended xvfb methods to work (from that same link).

Comment: As to what I am testing, I am just checking that the correct user-specified path is used when the page is exported. I don't actually need the `webbrowser` call when testing, but do when running in production. Is there a way only to run a command in one's code if a test is *not* being run? If so, I could just skip the `webbrowser` line when running under Travis.

Comment: Just found the Travis environment variables, so will probably just avoid the problem. Would still like to know the answer, though.

Comment: Maybe firefox is not set as the default browser? You could try setting the `BROWSER` environment variable (see your link above). Instead, have a look at the mock module which will let you check that open_new_tab() method is called with the proper parameter. You probably need to resort to dependency injection to route the calls to mock when testing and to the real webbrowser module when in production.